# Separar icons JSP CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, icons

Estou querendo separar meus icons, pois estão muitos juntos mas não estou conseguindo.Ao colocar o `padding` a aplicação fica assim.

Aumenta o `with` e `heigth` e não separando os icons.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.redes_sociais{
    padding: 30px;
}

.top{
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top">
    <li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Atendimento</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Ajuda</li>    
</ul>
<ul class="redes_sociais">
    <li><i class="fa fa-facebook" action="" ></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-twitter" action=""></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-linkedin" action=""></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-dribbble" action=""></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-google-plus" action=""></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Tens que adicionar o `padding: x` nos itens dentro do `<ul>`.

Comment: como assim tenho que criar uma div pra cada <li> ?

Answer (score 0):

O `padding` está sendo aplicado ao elemento `ul.redes_sociais`, e não aos itens dentro dele (`ul.redes_sociais > li`).

Adicione esse trecho no teu CSS:

```
.redes_sociais li {
  padding: 30px;
}
```